# Unable to Solve Simple DMOJ Math Question?

Tags: java

I am attempting to solve this problem: https://dmoj.ca/problem/thereturnofaplusb

My actual code for this problem receives a an ***Invalid Return*** for the test cases, ***InputMismatchException*** and a score of ***0/1521***. By manually typing in the inputs such as the sample inputs on the page, the code works fine, however the online judge on DMOJ deems it incorrect. Here is my code below for reference.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int l = input.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
            int a=input.nextInt();
            int b=input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(a+b);
        }
    }
}
```

I have found that by printing any same number from 2-20, ***N*** times, you can receive partial marks. By printing the number 2 **N** times, I receive a score of ***16/1521***. I have done this with every other value from 2-20 and found that by printing 11 **N** times, I can achieve the highest score of ***152/1521***, but I am still unable to achieve 1521/1521.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int l = input.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
            System.out.println("11");
        }
    }
}
```

How so I successfully solve this problem? I have asked my peers to solve this along with my computer science teacher and we've all been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really stupid exercise.
The trick is that the numbers might not be given in digits. They seem to appear as text in English and French, too. To make things even worse, they might also appear as Chinese symbols.

I wasn't able to solve this on my own, but I used a solution found in python here: https://github.com/plasmatic1/dmoj-solutions/blob/master/py/thereturnofaplusb.py

My Java solution derived from that implementation is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    private static final String[] EN_VALUES = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" };
    private static final String[] FR_VALUES = new String[] { "un", "deux", "trois", "quatre", "cinq", "seis", "sept", "huit", "neuf", "dix" };
    private static final String[] CN_VALUES = new String[] { "一", "二", "三", "四", "五", "六", "七", "八", "九", "十"};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8"))) {
            int lineCount = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
                String line = in.readLine();
                String[] token = line.split("\\s+");
                System.out.println(parseNum(token[0]) + parseNum(token[1]));
            }
        }
    }

    private static int parseNum(String token) {
        if (token.matches("\\d+")) {
            return Integer.parseInt(token);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < EN_VALUES.length; i++) {
            if (token.equalsIgnoreCase(EN_VALUES[i]) || token.equalsIgnoreCase(FR_VALUES[i]) || token.equalsIgnoreCase(CN_VALUES[i])) {
                return i + 1;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
```

I cannot find any clue in the description what symbols may appear in the input. And the stripped output from the response does not provide meaningful hints, at least for java. Why not add some roman numbers to the input? I, II, III, IV...

Comment: Truly a stupid excercise. And in the result they show you only single character of your program's output. I tried printing each character of the input one by one and found that input contains English words 'one', 'two', etc. and then gave up.